# Remove padding between plot and the axis - xchart

Tags: java, graph

Currently, I have this chart is created. But I can't seem to find any function in the documentation that removes the padding between the plot and the x / y axis (see image below).

[image]

Just so this can be replicated, I have included my code below.

```
 // Create Chart

        XYChart chart = new XYChartBuilder().width(640).height(450).build();

        // Customize Char


        chart.getStyler().setPlotBorderVisible(false);
        chart.getStyler().setMarkerSize(0);
        chart.getStyler().setPlotGridLinesVisible(false);
        chart.getStyler().setAxisTicksVisible(false);
        chart.getStyler().setLegendVisible(false);
        chart.getStyler().setChartPadding(0);

        chart.getStyler().setDefaultSeriesRenderStyle(XYSeries.XYSeriesRenderStyle.Area);

        // Series
        chart.addSeries("a", new double[] { 0, 3, 5}, new double[] { -3, 5, 9});
        chart.addSeries("b", new double[] { 5, 7, 9 }, new double[] { 9, 6, 5});


        try {
            BitmapEncoder.saveBitmap(chart, "./report-template/chart/Sample_Chart.png", BitmapEncoder.BitmapFormat.PNG);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException( "Failed to save the chart!!! \n" + e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I try same thing, and it helps me.

```
chart.getStyler().setPlotContentSize(1d);
```

document: https://knowm.org/javadocs/xchart/org/knowm/xchart/style/Styler.html#setPlotContentSize(double)